# Unfiltering in R to mutate a variable in a data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set of open-answer responses in a survey. I have a set of topics that I want to assign to these open answer responses according to the content of the people's responses to a given question.

I want to specify keywords and search for a match to these keywords (/strings) for a specific variable (in this case, the variable is a question asked). Importantly, these strings can only be a partial match to the responses, I'm just specifying keywords that will appear at some point in the string. For example, filtering the responses by those that use the word 'money' at some point in their response to a given question. Given the matched rows, I want to assign a "1" to those rows in a new variable, let's call it "Topic1".

I have this code:

```
df %>% 
  filter(str_detect(var, "money|cash|revenue|profit")) %>% 
  mutate(Topic1 = "1")
```

This code works fine to filter and create the new variable according to the conditions I specify. However, if I assign back to the dataframe, I have now subsetted the entire dataframe according to my filter. I would like to filter the rows by my provided keywords, create the new variable, then 'unfilter' the dataframe, and assign the result back to the df.

I'm wondering if there is an 'unfilter' that I can use to reselect all my data. OR perhaps there is a better solution with ifelse?

Comment: You are on the right track with `ifelse`. Try `df %>% mutate(Topic1 = ifelse(str_detect(var, "money|cash|revenue|profit"), "1", "0"))`

Comment: `ifelse` is not needed, turn logical values to numeric - `mutate(Topic1 = as.numeric(grepl("money|cash|revenue|profit", var)))`

Comment: AH!!!!!!! Brilliant, thanks. So obvious but also I would have googled my way into infinity before I realised. Cheers!

Comment: @PoGibas great, that's clever. Thank you. Both options are working, thanks :D